# Camera RRF tag in Android application

Tags: android, camera, logcat, rtsp

I'm testing my Android application on a Mediacom Android device and and some other devices. 
When I try to stream a content over **RTSP**, I can see this message repeated in 'Camera' **tag** in Logcat and the streaming doesn't start:

...
Camera RRF

Camera RRF

Camera RRF

Camera RRF

Camera RRF

...

I can't find anything on the net about this tag...
Anyone know how to deal with this issue ?